# Printing on a new line every time I run?

Tags: python

My code below:

```
import random
lines = open('/Users/xxx/Desktop/wordlist.text).read().splitlines()
words random.choice(lines)

guesses = ''
turns = 10
while turns > 0:
    failed = 0
    for char in word:
        if char = " "
            print (char),
        elif char in guesses:
            print(char)
        else:
            print("_")
            failed += 1

    if failed == 0
        print("You won")
```

Output:

```
Start Guessing
_
_
_
_
_
_
guess a character:
```

How do I make it so that the underscores are next to each other like this:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _
```

I don't understand why they are printing on new lines every time?

Comment: To make it easy for people reading your question, please edit to put the code and problem in the question itself, rather than an image link.

Comment: I would suggest you to paste the code instead of taking a screenshot. This time I will do it for you.

Comment: Please select an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python3, use `print('_', end='')` in place of `end='\n'` by default.
In python2, use `print '_',` (single element tuple) to avoid NEWLINE behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The default end is newline ‘\n’. You can change that like this:
print('_ ', end='')